# Fill a timeseries plot

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have this piece of code and what i'm trying to do is to fill this function plot that is made with timeseries.  I tried full and area methods, but didn't have any success to implement them. I also tried to plot using TP1out to plot instead of TP1, but doing this i lose my ZOH interpolation and the graph become linear. If someone have an idea how to solve this i would be thankful.

```
TP1out = [1 0 0 1 0];
time = 0:4; 
TP1 = timeseries(TP1out,time,'name','task 1');
TP1.DataInfo.Interpolation = tsdata.interpolation('zoh');
plot(TP1), grid on
axis([0 4 0 1.5])
```

[image]

I know it's stupid, but i tried many stuff, like:

```
>> area(TP1)
Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type
'timeseries'.

Error in xychk (line 48)
    x = real(y); y = imag(y);

Error in area (line 45)
            [msg,x,y] = xychk(args{1:nargs},'plot');

>> area(time,TP1)
Error using specgraph.areaseries/set
Array must be numeric or logical.

Error in specgraph.areaseries (line 40)
  set(h,args{:})

Error in area (line 83)
                    h = [h
                    specgraph.areaseries('YData',datachk(y(:,k)),
                    ...

>> area(time,TP1.Data)
Error using area (line 46)
Inputs must be 2-D.
```

Comment: Could you tag your question with the language that you are using? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's Matlab.

Comment: [area](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/area.html) and [fill](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) are both appropriate for your purpose. You mention that you've tried them - that's good! You don't give an example of *what* you tried with them, or where/how it didn't work for you - that's not so good. I suggest trying again with one or both of those functions; if needed, try just plotting a simple rectangle first. If you still need help, post some of the code you've come up with.